# Communicate Java with OpenDSS through dl

Tags: java

I am making an external call to Java with the OpenDSS dll (simulator of the electricity distribution network). I did a search and found some forms, for example, using Com4j, JNI and JNA. Among them, I observed that JNA is simplified, however, I need to implement an interface to declare the methods that will be used in this communication.
Someone how do I do this?